# Shape operator of a strictly convex surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Define a strictly convex surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be one that bounds a strictly convex closed region. Is it true that the Gauss map on this surface has invertible derivative everywhere? Clearly the second fundamental form is non-negative definite, but must it be positive definite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Such a surface must be "positively curved" in the sense that it contacts each tangent plane at exactly one point, but the second fundamental form only measures 2nd order effects, and this may only happen at higher order. With this in mind, consider the following surface:
$$
\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^4+y^4+z^4=1\}
$$
One can show that this surface is strictly convex, but its second fundamental form vanishes at $(0,0,1)$.